# Что означает данное приведение типа

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

В статье в по адресу https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform наткнулся на такое приведение типа:

```
(int (*)(int))std::toupper
```

Как правильно прочитать данное приведение типа, и для чего оно нужно.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`int (*)(int)` - указатель (`(*)`) на функцию от `int` (`(int)`), которая возвращает `int`.

```
int (*)(int)
     ^ указатель
       ^ на функцию от int
^ возвращающую int
```

Comment: а зачем нужно это приведение? просто имени функции не достаточно?

Comment: @Stanislav Petrov: Функция `toupper` в стандартной библиотеке С++ является перегруженной. Приведение типа - как раз способ выбрать одну функцию из набора перегруженных.

Comment: круто, прикольно, молодцы парни!!!